# Logic for creating a home page for the forum

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am not looking for any code in particular but I am more interested in the logic. So here is the question.

I want to create a forum. The home page shows the top 20 questions that have been asked recently and have been stored in the database.
I have used ajax and php to fetch the information from the database. The issue is, how do I display this information?

Should I make 20 identical divs and display the contents of each row in these divs.(this wouldn't make sense if I have to display 300-400 questions at once )

Or, should I use jquery to append child divs in a parent div and display information dynamically? If yes then how can it be done?

My question may be a bit unclear but I am a bit clueless here. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question leads to many possibilities. Here is one...

## Button to pass id

`<button class="" data-id="ID HERE" id="getAnswer">Get Answer</button>`

## Div to Return Data to

`<div id="returnProcessedData"></div>`

## Hidden Input to Store Processing URL

`<input type="hidden" id="processURL" value="process.php">`

## jQquery

```
$( "#getAnswer" ).click(function(){
        var url = $('#processURL').val();
        var theid = $(this).attr('data-id');                    
        var postit = $.post( url, {theid:theid});       
        postit.done(function( data ) {
        $( "#returnProcessedData" ).html(data).slideToggle("slow");     
        });     
    });
```

Do all your processing on `process.php` whatever you `echo` on `process.php` will render in `<div id="returnProcessedData"></div>`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This isn't exactly what i was looking for but you did give me an idea and it worked :)